# Loading the XML in PhoneGap for Window Phones is not working

Tags: xml, internet-explorer, cordova, windows-phone, activexobject

I am developing a PhoneGap app for Window Phones.

In my app I am trying to load an XML from the app itself but it fails to load the xmll, my code is :

```
xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
    xmlDoc.async = false;
    while (xmlDoc.readyState != 4) { };
    xmlDoc.load(xmlFile);
    traverseDOM();
```

I have Googled it and found the code is fine for loading the XML in Internet Explorer, but my XML is not loading..

Please help me as I am new to this platform.

Comment: does anybody not have any idea or solution for this problem....

Comment: Are you working in VS? Is the XML file local? If yes and the file is located within the www folder then my first thought would be to make sure the Build Action property of the file is set to "Content."

Comment: Yes, i am working in VS.My XML is local and its in "XML" folder under "WWW" folder and the build action is already set to "Content"

Answer (score 1):

You can't create an ActiveXObject on Windows phone - you have to use XMLHttpRequest instead.  check this out: http://css.dzone.com/articles/xmlhttprequest-calls-ie-9

Answer (score 0):

```
I had the same issue in windows phone.I used the code below to solve this. Using ajax query. **isLocal** parameter is mandatory to access local files.

  var url = 'BranchDetail.xml';
            $.ajax({
                type:'GET',
                dataType: "xml",
                url: url,
                async: false,
                isLocal: true, // For the damn Windows Phone
                success: function (xml) {
                    $(xml).find('ROW').each(function () {
                        var title = $(this).find('BRANCH_EN_NAME').text();
                        alert(title);
                    });
                },
                error: function (xhr, error, exception) {
                    alert(" - Exception: " + exception);
                }
            });
```